# add layouts dynamically in view group

Tags: android-layout

I want to add four relative layouts dynamically with different colors. when i try to add that, the container contains four childviews. but three layouts are only visible. how to make visible that first layouts.

my code

```
int[] colors={Color.RED,Color.BLACK,Color.BLUE,Color.YELLOW};
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            RelativeLayout relativeLayout=new RelativeLayout(MainActivity.this);
            relativeLayout.setId(i);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(2400,100);                 
            if(i>0){
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,audioContainer.getChildAt(i-1).getId());
            }
            relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);   
            relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(colors[i]);
            audioContainer.addView(relativeLayout);         

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because ids must be positive numbers. You could simply add 1:

```
relativeLayout.setId(i + 1);
```

Doing what you want is usually much easier when the container is a LinearLayout with vertical orientation. You can simply add views and do not have to specify any layout rules or ids.